# Is the're any level of importance in creating html input attribute

Tags: html

I was got a question about what comes first for declaring attribute do they have level of importance?

Like type must comes first

```
<input type="" name="" value="">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a specific order that HTTP tag attributes should be listed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817542/is-there-a-specific-order-that-http-tag-attributes-should-be-listed-in)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no importance in the order in which attributes are declared. Except if you declare an attribute twice, then the second overrides the first.

Comment: So i can make value or name attribute first before type? but i don't think that's good approach?